# Permutation in Python - template

Tags: python, permutation

I want to create function for every possible permutation of an array. I wrote some code and I don't know what is wrong with it. It return me first possibility = [1,2,3], but then It fails with error : original[i] out of index but it should be originial[1] which equals 2. Maybe del temp erases also from original but that would not make sense for me.

Thank you in advace.

```
array = [1,2,3]
out = []

def permutacja(original,perm):
    if(len(original) == 0):
        print(perm)
        return perm

    temp = original
    for i in range(0,len(original)):
        perm.append(original[i])
        del temp[0]
        permutacja(temp,perm)
        del perm[len(perm)-1]

permutacja(array,out)
```

Comment: yep, temp erases also from original
`tmp = array #copies the reference to list`

insdead you should use:

`tmp = list(array)`

Answer (score 4):

Python standard library module `itertools` provide [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) which yields permutations:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for xs in itertools.permutations([1,2,3]):
...     print(xs)
...
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: thanks, but I need this for more complicate algorithm which includes different type of data, I need to understand a simple way to do it to implicate this then to my algorithm

Comment: @user3541098, Okay, I will give you a hint about your implementation problem. By doing `temp = original`, `temp` references the same list (not copying). By doing `temp = original[:]`, you will get a copy.

Comment: @user3541098: `itertools` works with all kinds of data: strings, ints, floats, objects, etc.

Comment: oh, ok, that would explain everything, thank you very much

Comment: @user3541098, `perm[len(perm)-1]` can be expressed as `perm[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You better use `itertools` for this since these are well optimized and tested routines. Nevertheless in case you want to implement it yourself, there are some things that can be improved/corrected:

- You `return` a value, but only in the last recursive step you need to **propagate them back**;
- you return a **reference** to the list you construct on the fly, as a result you will always return the same list;
- you always `del`ete the **first element**, not the one you picked; and
- you do **not restore** the element after deletion.

```
def permutacja(original,perm):
    if(len(original) == 0):
        print(perm)
        yield perm.copy() # emit instead of return for proagation
    else:
        temp = original
        for i in range(0,len(original)):
            perm.append(original[i])
            temp = original[:i]+original[i+1:] #remove the i-th
            for result in permutacja(temp,perm):
                yield result # propagate back
            del perm[len(perm)-1]
            # because we copy original, no need to restore
```

Some additonal improvements:

- use `.pop()` instead of `del` on the last element; and
- you can simply use `if original` instead of a comparison on `len(..)`:

```
def permutacja(original,perm):
    if original:
        print(perm)
        yield perm.copy()
    else:
        temp = original
        for i in range(0,len(original)):
            perm.append(original[i])
            temp = original[:i]+original[i+1:] #remove the i-th
            for result in permutacja(temp,perm):
                yield result # propagate back
            perm.pop()
            # because we copy original, no need to restore
```